# Установка WDK 10 на Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, sdk

Пытаюсь второй день поставить WDK (интересует windbg) на windows 8.1. Установил все важные обновления системы, Visual Studio 15 community с windows sdk.
WDK беру с официального сайта https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit. 
Однако при установке выдает, что требуется 0 байт места, установка успешна, однако вожделенного windbg я не обнаруживаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск в интернете похожих проблем не нашел. Как это можно исправить?